# Duplicate ID's with different values in rows

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with a dataset I am using for my thesis. The dataset contains customer purchase information and I want to figure out how many times a customer has purchased, what the total purchase amount is and what their average spending is. The data I currently have looks something like this:

```
    id      date        total_purchase_amount   product_price
0   84288   2020-1-1    100                     50
1   84288   2020-1-1                            50
2   84288   2020-3-7    80                      20
3   84288   2020-3-7                            60
4   84289   2020-8-16   200                     10
5   84289   2020-8-16                           50
6   84289   2020-8-16                           10
7   84288   2020-8-16                           80
8   84290   2020-4-2    10                      10
9   84290   2020-4-8    30                      30
10  84291   2020-5-23   45                      45
```

Some customers have made purchases more than once, causing their customer ID to appear multiple times in the dataset. What I want to achieve is a dataset which looks this:

```
   id      total_purchase_amount   average_spending    times_purchased
0   84288   180                     45                  2
1   84289   200                     37,5                1
2   84290   40                      20                  2
3   84291   45                      45                  1
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can achieve this? The dataset I work with is very large, so this problem cannot be solved manually.

Here is the code to get the first dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[84288, "2020-1-1", 100, 50],[84288, "2020-1-1", "", 50],[84288, "2020-3-7", 80, 20], [84288, "2020-3-7", "", 60],[84289, "2020-8-16", 200, 10],[84289, "2020-8-16", "", 50],[84289, "2020-8-16", "", 10], [84289, "2020-8-16", "", 80],[84290, "2020-4-2", 10, 10],[84290, "2020-4-8", 30, 30],[84291, "2020-5-23", 45, 45]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','date','total_purchase_amount','purchase_amount'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the blank rows with NA and do the math in the grouping.

```
df.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)
df.groupby('id')[['total_purchase_amount','purchase_amount']].agg(average_spending=('purchase_amount','mean'),times_purchased=('total_purchase_amount','count'))

       average_spending times_purchased
id      
84288   45.0    2
84289   37.5    1
84290   20.0    2
84291   45.0    1
```